# Unsnapping two items that have accidentally been snapped in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, digitizing, qgis-3

In QGIS 3 how can I "unsnap" two items that have accidentally been snapped?

So far the only way I have found of unsnapping is to delete the vertex and re-add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, simply moving the vertex is enough, the other vertices should not move. It seems like you have topological editing enabled, you can simply disable it using the icon on the snapping toolbar.